# Gebrane's Hanoi

Tags: trigonometry, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

I need some help to solve a modification of the Tower of Hanoi problem found on a french forum.

The classic problem is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi).

This modification is called Gebrane's Hanoi problem (from the name of its inventor), the $n$ disks are numbered from top to bottom from $1$ to $n$ and are also placed on peg $A$, and the goal is to move all the disks to pegs $B$ and $C$ to form two towers: the tower on peg $B$ is formed with all the even-numbered disks and the one on peg $C$ is formed with all the odd ones (obviously).
The other rules are the same: each move consist in displacing an upper disk of a tower on top of another tower or on an empty peg, and no disk may be placed on a smaller one.
Let $HG(n)$ be the minimum number of moves to solve Gebrane's Hanoi problem.

Prove that: $$HG(n)=-\frac 1{21}\cos\left(\frac2 3n\pi\right)+\frac 1 7\sqrt 3\sin\left(\frac2 3n\pi\right)+\frac 5 7 2^n-\frac 2 3.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rename pegs $B$ and $C$ as $B'$ and $C'$ where $B'$ is the peg where
disc $n$ and all other discs with the same parity are destined to move, and
$C'$ is where the discs of opposite parity are to go.

Let $n\ge3$.

We need to move disc $n$ to $B'$. First we need to move discs $1$ to $n-1$ to $C'$;
this needs $2^{n-1}-1$ moves. After $2^{n-1}$ moves we have disc $n$ on $B'$
the remaining discs on $C'$ and $A$ empty.

Both discs $n-1$ and $n$ are where we want them. We need to move disc $n-2$
to $B'$. So we need to move discs $1$ to $n-3$ from $C'$ to $A$, which takes
$2^{n-3}-1$ moves, then an extra move to get $n-2$ to $B'$.
After $2^{n-1}+2^{n-3}$ moves, we have $n-2$ and $n$ on $B'$ and $n-1$ on $C'$,
and the remaining discs on $A$.

We are back to the original puzzle but with $n$ replaced by $n-3$.
Therefore
$$HG(n)=HG(n-3)+2^{n-1}+2^{n-3}=HG(n-3)+\frac58 2^{n}.$$
Now solve this recurrence
(the solution will have the form $a2^n+b+c\cos(2n\pi/3)+d\sin(2n\pi/3)$).

Comment: @ Angina Seng thank you so much. but do we have to calculate by hand HG (3), HG (4) and HG (5) necessarily to calculate the constants? 
If $HG(n+3)=HG(n)+\frac 5 8 2^{n+3},\quad \forall n\geq 0$  will suffice  to calculate HG(0), HG(1) and HG(2)

Comment: You'll need to start the recurrence somewhere.... @cerise